# Evaluate $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \sqrt[n]{\frac{1^n+2^n+3^n+\cdots +n^n}{1+2!+3!+\cdots +n!}}$

Tags: calculus, limits

Evaluate the following limit:
$$
\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \sqrt[n]{\frac{1^n+2^n+3^n+\cdots +n^n}{1+2!+3!+\cdots +n!}}
$$

I tried to apply [Stirling's approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation), but it seems that it doesn't work. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let's use the squeeze theorem. First,
$$
\sqrt[n]{\frac{\sum_{k=1}^n k^n}{\sum_{k=1}^n k!}}
\leq 
\sqrt[n]{\frac{n\cdot n^n}{n!}}
= n^{1/n} \sqrt[n]{\frac{n^n}{n!}}
\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{} 1\cdot e = e
$$
by, e.g., Stirling's approximation.

Second,
$$
\sqrt[n]{\frac{\sum_{k=1}^n k^n}{\sum_{k=1}^n k!}}
\geq 
\sqrt[n]{\frac{n^n}{n\cdot n!}}
= \frac{1}{n^{1/n}} \sqrt[n]{\frac{n^n}{n!}}
\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{} e
$$
for the same reason.

Comment: Wow. I forgot the squeeze theorem. Nice proof.

Comment: Thanks! ${}{}{}{}$